# Personalised directory structure deploying with Maven

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have just recently started working with Maven and I have been asked to create a specific structure for when we deploy. The structure has to look like this:

> /opt
>
> > \-myproject
> >
> > > |- libs
> > >
> > > |- conf
> > >
> > > \- logs

libs - Contains all the dependent libs and our own myproject.jar

conf - Contains the .properties files

logs - Contains our log file myproject.log

Our current java structure looks like this:

> /src
>
> > |-myprojectpackages
> >
> > propertiesfile1.properties
> >
> > propertiesfile2.properties
>
> pom.xml

My question is, do I have to change the java structure or is there any way to specify it in the pom.xml file? How should I handle this with Maven?

Edit: 
In the end I used the Maven default layout, as advised in the comments section.

Comment: You should take a look at the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which can create what ever structure you like. But you structure in your projects should follow the [maven default layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)...(src/main/java, src/main/resources etc.). Maven foundation is based on conventions and i would follow them. There is no good reason to violate them. The folder structure of your maven project is not related to the structure your distribution archive has.

Comment: Agree with @khmarbaise, which makes this question too broad.